# Can I exit the second client without closing the first client's buffers that were opened in the second client?

Tags: buffers, emacsclient

First I ran `emacs --daemon`.

Then in one shell, I ran `emacsclient -nw` and open several files in the buffer.

Then in another shell, I did the same thing. At the same time I found that the file buffers I opened in the second client also appear in the first client.

When I exit the second client with `ctrl-x ctrl-c`, the buffers created in the second client also disappear from the first client.
Can I exit the second client without closing the first client's buffers that were opened in the second client?

Thanks.

My `init.el`

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                 

;; 1. markdown.el for markdown languages                                                                                                                                          

;; place `markdown-mode.el` somewhere in the load-path and add                                                                                                                    
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/markdown/") ;; added by me                                                                                                              

;; autoload the el file                                                                                                                                                           
(autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode"
  "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)

;; the following lines to your `.emacs` file to associate markdown-mode                                                                                                           
;; with `.text`, `.markdown`, and `.md` files:                                                                                                                                    
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                   
;; Added by me                                                                                                                                                                    

;; 2. ESS for R language,                                                                                                                                                         
;; (require 'ess-site) ;; TODO: not working                                                                                                                                       

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                              

;; 3. go-mode for go language                                                                                                                                                     
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elisp/go-mode/")
(require 'go-mode-autoloads)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                              

; 4. Enable installation of packages from MELPA                                                                                                                                   

(require 'package) ;; You might already have this line                                                                                                                            
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib                                                                                                                            
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize) ;; You might already have this line                                                                                                                          

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                                                                                                                                                  
; 5. for saving emacs sessions                                                                                                                                                    
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Can you do this without any init file `-Q`?

Comment: Do I need to terminate the emacs daemon right now and restart it as `emacs -daemon -Q`? Or do you mean I just run `emacsclient -nw -Q`?

Comment: You want to start the daemon without loading init files, clients just connect to it, and I don't think this option is even supported at all by `emacsclient`.

Comment: I have to load settings in init.el and can't terminate the daemon right now. My init.el isn't complicated. See my update.

Comment: `C-x C-c` shouldn't kill buffers under any circumstance according to docstrings, and `desktop-mode` doesn't mention changing how that key behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the client is closed, `server-delete-client` is going to kill all (unmodified) buffers which were *explicitly* associated with (only) that client.

You can prevent that by customizing `server-kill-new-buffers` to `nil`

Comment: Thanks. Is `(server-kill-new-buffers  nil)` the correct one to put inside `init.el`? How would you modify `init.el` for that purpose?

Comment: It's a variable (and a user option), so either `(setq server-kill-new-buffers nil)` or use `M-x customize-option RET server-kill-new-buffers`